# Loop not executing more than once

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, iteration, java.util.scanner

I'm supposed to make a program that continuously accepts desk  order data and displays all the relevant information for oak desks that are over 36 inches long and have at least one drawer.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MangMaxB 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char ans;
        int orderNum=0, length=0, width=0, numDrawer=0, price=1000;
        String name;

        System.out.print("Do you wish to enter Oak " +
                        "desk order data? (y/n)");
        ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

        while (ans != 'n')
        {  
            System.out.print("Enter customer name: ");
            name=input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter order number: ");
            orderNum=input.nextInt();    

            System.out.print("Enter length and width of Oak desk" +
                        " separated by a space: ");
            length = input.nextInt();
            width = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter number of drawer/s: ");
            numDrawer=input.nextInt();

            if ((length>36)&&(numDrawer>=1))
            {
                if ((length*width)>750)
                {
                    price+= 250;
                }

                price+= (numDrawer*100);
                price+= 300;

                System.out.println("\nOak desk order information:\n" 
                        + "Order number: " + orderNum + "\n"
                        + "Customer name: " + name + "\n"
                        + "Length: " + length + ", width: "
                        + width + ", surface: " + (length*width)
                        + "\n" + "Number of drawer/s: " + numDrawer
                        + "\nPrice of the desk is P " + price);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("\nOak desk order isn't over 36 " +
                        "inches long and doesn't have a drawer");
            }

            System.out.print("Any more items? (y/n) ");
            ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to enter data and display it but on the second attempt since it is a loop, it didn't work.

It says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at controlStruc.MangMaxB.main"

how do I fix this?

Comment: Why not just deal with the `String` objects? No real point in getting the `char` out of the `String`. In any case, it looks to me like it should work, are you sure you entered a character when it asked? If you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> there wouldn't be a `char` at position 0 in the `String`.

Comment: well, it appears to me as though `input.nextLine()` is an empty string at the end of your loop

Comment: @SamIam It's *why* it's an empty string though that's the real question here!

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I agree that there's little point using chars, but you're incorrect in that the code won't work in its current form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use like the below,

```
System.out.print("Any more items? (y/n) ");  
input = new Scanner(System.in);  
ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

beacuse input.nextLine() returns empty string, so when try to get 0th char  it returns StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
You need to get a String before calling input.nextLine()

Comment: -1: The allocation of the new scanner is an unnecessary overhead, and avoids the real source of the problem here.

Answer (score 6):

`nextInt()` doesn't read the end of the line - just the next integer. You need to call `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` if you want to read the remainder of that line.

At present, you're not doing so, so the last `nextLine()` method just reads the rest of the empty line after the integer, and returns immediately with an empty string, causing the exception.

In this case, putting a `nextLine()` call here should do the trick:

```
System.out.print("Enter number of drawer/s: ");
numDrawer=input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); //Added nextLine() call
```

Comment: do I add input.nextLine(); in all the line after input.nextInt(); ??

Comment: @DohaKik In this example I believe it's only necessary to add it on the line I've specified.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just pressing enter?

```
ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

is throwing this error when it's an empty string. Your exception is clearly telling you this. You need to check if the "nextLine" is an empty string or not.

Comment: Perhaps the check should be there as good practice, but this isn't the issue - the problem is that the nextLine() will always (in the scenario where the user enters correct input) return immediately, since the nextInt() call doesn't cause the scanner to parse the end of the line the integer is on.

Comment: Yes I press enter. how do i fix this? After I enter customer name, it generates errors

Answer (score 0):

Clearly according to documentaion:

`nextLine()`-`Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.`

`nextInt()`-`Scans the next token of the input as an int.`

And henceforth `ans = input.nextLine()` in your code is returning you with `''` and `char(0)` leading for `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I presume your second reference to nextLine() is actually meant to be nextInt()?